# Which is the best JPA L2 Cache provider?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, memcached, ehcache

This references a question I asked earlier: [Scaling and Clustering JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328581/scaling-and-clustering-jpa). It appears there are many choices when it comes to the use of a JPA Cache. I am leaning towards memcached since it appears to have broad support, including outside of Java environment. I have used ehcache outside of JPA in the past and have liked it. My constraint is that I am on JBoss 7 with MySQL Cluster as backing storage. Our JPA provider currently is Hibernate but we are open to change if there is a robust provider that is easy to work with vis a vis distributed caching. My choices appear to be:

- Memcached
- Ehcache
- JBoss Cache
- Toplink Grid

I would love to hear qualified answers that would let me choose.

Thanks for your insights.

-Raj

Comment: Your choices are actually defined by your JPA implementation and what it provides support for, yet you don't say which that is ...

Comment: Hi DataNucleus, thanks for your comment. We are currently on Hibernate and open to change. I updated the question description above.

Answer (score 1):

Ehcache is ok - solid project. There were (are?) problems with JBoss Cache performance [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346357/performance-of-jboss-cache-and-ehcache]. I would add to the list infinispan (by JBoss people as well), but I've never used it.

Comment: Hi Piotr, thanks for your response. JBossCache seems EOL. Infinispan's website seems to say effusively good things about it (surprise!). Do you know which JPA provider it plays well with?

Comment: For sure it works properly with Hibernate JPA implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Hazelcast. It provides Hibernate 2nd level cache out of the box. See http://hazelcast.com/docs/2.1/manual/single_html/#HibernateSecondLevelCache for more information

Note: I work for Hazelcast